# Gwt, I don't wanna use drag n drop (DnD) since it may not work on other browser, so What are the alternative to DnD?

Tags: gwt, user-interface, drag-and-drop

Here is my problem, I got a list of widget on 1 Panel (Panel 1), there another panel (panel 2) that have many cells/slots on it.

I want to build a program that let users to bring any widget in panel 1 & put it into 1 cell/slot of panel 2.

You may say that I can use Drag n Drop (DnD) in Gwt but some other browser does not support DnD. I want my program to be stable rather than fancy.

I just want to use normal (non-fancy) way of coding. So What are the alternatives to DnD?

What is the easiest way to let users to bring a widget from panel 1 into panel 2?

I want it to be as easy as DnD action, but the code should be much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/

It's an easy, simple, DOM-based drag&drop library. In its [showcase](https://gwt-dnd.appspot.com/#InsertPanelExample), you can see what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If DnD is not a reliable option (or if users have problems with it), then there's always the "good old" way of putting left/right arrow buttons between the panels:

https://mockupstogo.mybalsamiq.com/projects/controls/Dual%20Select

... and probably adding up/down arrows to change the ordering of elements.